# Linux ActiveMQ destinations Topic startup

Tags: activemq-classic, startup, jms-topic

I am trying to setup a Topic at startup of ActiveMQ. We will have Durable subscribers but they are not yet available.

Startup Config says to add:

```
<destinations>
  <queue physicalName="FOO.BAR" />
  <topic physicalName="SOME.TOPIC" />
</destinations>
```

I have added this to activemq.xml but no luck. No Topic is created at startup of ActiveMQ. We are running 5.7.

Ideas?

EDIT:

I am trying to setup a Topic on Startup of ActiveMQ. When ActiveMQ is restarted (or shutdown and started) Topics are deleted because they are in memory. I want to add a Topic in the XML configuration so it is created on the fly when AMQ is started. in this way our ESB can reach it directly and can start to work. The ESB will be a Durable subscriber but not yet. Still implementing. The documentation says to add to above rows in the XML config. But I have no luck with that. A Topic is not created upon start.

So my I will just add them whereever?

```
  <beans
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
 http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

<!-- Allows us to use system properties as variables in this configuration file -->
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <value>file:${activemq.conf}/credentials.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<!--
    The <broker> element is used to configure the ActiveMQ broker.
-->
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="localhost" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}">

    <!-- Like here? -->
    <destinations>
       <queue physicalName="FOO.BAR" />
       <topic physicalName="SOME.TOPIC" />
    </destinations>
    <!--
        For better performances use VM cursor and small memory limit.
        For more information, see:

        http://activemq.apache.org/message-cursors.html

        Also, if your producer is "hanging", it's probably due to producer flow control.
        For more information, see:
        http://activemq.apache.org/producer-flow-control.html
    -->

    <destinationPolicy>
        <policyMap>
          <policyEntries>
            <policyEntry topic=">" producerFlowControl="true">
                <!-- The constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy is used to prevent
                     slow topic consumers to block producers and affect other consumers
                     by limiting the number of messages that are retained
                     For more information, see:

                     http://activemq.apache.org/slow-consumer-handling.html

                -->
              <pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                <constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy limit="1000"/>
              </pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
            </policyEntry>
            <policyEntry queue=">" producerFlowControl="true" memoryLimit="1mb">
              <!-- Use VM cursor for better latency
                   For more information, see:

                   http://activemq.apache.org/message-cursors.html

              <pendingQueuePolicy>
                <vmQueueCursor/>
              </pendingQueuePolicy>
              -->
            </policyEntry>
          </policyEntries>
        </policyMap>
    </destinationPolicy>


    <!--
        The managementContext is used to configure how ActiveMQ is exposed in
        JMX. By default, ActiveMQ uses the MBean server that is started by
        the JVM. For more information, see:

        http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html
    -->
    <managementContext>
        <managementContext createConnector="false"/>
    </managementContext>

    <!--
        Configure message persistence for the broker. The default persistence
        mechanism is the KahaDB store (identified by the kahaDB tag).
        For more information, see:

        http://activemq.apache.org/persistence.html
    -->
    <persistenceAdapter>
        <kahaDB directory="${activemq.data}/kahadb"/>
    </persistenceAdapter>


      <!--
        The systemUsage controls the maximum amount of space the broker will
        use before slowing down producers. For more information, see:
        http://activemq.apache.org/producer-flow-control.html
        If using ActiveMQ embedded - the following limits could safely be used:

    <systemUsage>
        <systemUsage>
            <memoryUsage>
                <memoryUsage limit="20 mb"/>
            </memoryUsage>
            <storeUsage>
                <storeUsage limit="1 gb"/>
            </storeUsage>
            <tempUsage>
                <tempUsage limit="100 mb"/>
            </tempUsage>
        </systemUsage>
    </systemUsage>
    -->
      <systemUsage>
        <systemUsage>
            <memoryUsage>
                <memoryUsage limit="64 mb"/>
            </memoryUsage>
            <storeUsage>
                <storeUsage limit="100 gb"/>
            </storeUsage>
            <tempUsage>
                <tempUsage limit="50 gb"/>
            </tempUsage>
        </systemUsage>
    </systemUsage>

    <!--
        The transport connectors expose ActiveMQ over a given protocol to
        clients and other brokers. For more information, see:

        http://activemq.apache.org/configuring-transports.html
    -->
    <transportConnectors>
        <!-- DOS protection, limit concurrent connections to 1000 and frame size to 100MB -->
        <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireformat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:5672?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireformat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
    </transportConnectors>

    <!-- destroy the spring context on shutdown to stop jetty -->
    <shutdownHooks>
        <bean xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" class="org.apache.activemq.hooks.SpringContextHook" />
    </shutdownHooks>

</broker>

<!--
    Enable web consoles, REST and Ajax APIs and demos

    Take a look at ${ACTIVEMQ_HOME}/conf/jetty.xml for more details
-->
<import resource="jetty.xml"/>
```

/Ziggy

Comment: You need to expand on what you are trying to do and what the problem is.  Its not clear what your question really is.

Comment: See edit. I am trying to setup a Topic upon start of AMQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My own solution works. Though in our Linux environment we had more than one instance. One under /user/share and one under /home/activemq/

So it worked when I edited the corret file.

Thank you for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

I just dropped those into a vanilla 5.7 AMQ installation (on MacOS) and I see the both the queue and topic via the web console...

you should try again with a clean install of AMQ to try to narrow the issue down

Answer (score 0):

Put your destination inside `<destinations>` tag like

```
<destinations>
   <queue physicalName="FOO.BAR" />
   <topic physicalName="SOME.TOPIC" />
</destinations>
```

inside

`<broker></broker>` tags.